# unable to open file (in target "React" in project "Pods") (in target 'React')

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native

I have one reactNative project and i am trying to run in latest xcode 10.1.But its throwing two error while i building.

**error :**

```
Users/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/React/React.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "React" in project "Pods") (in target 'React')

Users/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/React/React.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "React" in project "Pods") (in target 'React')
```

my pod file is like below :

```
 source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'

EXPO_CPP_HEADER_DIR = 'ExpoKit'

target 'commonalityre' do
  pod 'ExpoKit',
    :git => "http://github.com/expo/expo.git",
    :tag => "ios/2.6.8",
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "CPP",
      "GL"
    ],
    :inhibit_warnings => true

  pod 'React',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :inhibit_warnings => true,
    :subspecs => [
      "Core",
      "ART",
      "RCTActionSheet",
      "RCTAnimation",
      "RCTCameraRoll",
      "RCTGeolocation",
      "RCTImage",
      "RCTNetwork",
      "RCTPushNotification",
      "RCTText",
      "RCTVibration",
      "RCTWebSocket",
      "DevSupport",
      "CxxBridge"
    ]
  pod 'yoga',
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga",
    :inhibit_warnings => true
```

Not sure how can i solve this. I tried deleting derived data, and clean, nothing help. Still i am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: I guess, you have only your iOS Folder. You need your node module folder. Where its reference is takes inside the pod

Answer (score 13):

Following should work:

1.

```sh
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

2.

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf ios/build/* && rm -rf android/build/* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && yarn cache clean && rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-* && yarn
```