# Can't add nor delete changes to my project on Xcode anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I dropped my laptop recently so it had to be sent to the Apple Center for a repair. When I got it back, I tried to open my Xcode project I have been working quite for a while, every time I open the project, I can't add nor delete changes. As I tap on the view controllers and the storyboard, they seem to be static and non accessible. I will add the screen of Xcode running on my laptop to show the problem. In addition, I also tried to run the project on a simulator but the Xcode showed me an error.

Here is what I am getting as an error:

> /Users/zhalyn/Desktop/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TestAPP/Pods-TestAPP.debug.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "AllerScan" in project "AllerScan")

[image]

Comment: The files seem to exist, so find them on disk and migrate them into a new project.

Comment: Try to rename your file `+UImage.swift` to `Something+UIImage.swift` (at least to fix the spelling). And show us the actual error message, as plain text.

Comment: Duplicates: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003931/cocoapods-debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-in-target), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57702726/debug-xcconfig-unable-to-open-file-in-project-reactiveobjc-in-target-reac), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262276/build-failed-unable-to-open-file-in-target-in-project-in-target) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036204/unable-to-open-file-in-target-react-in-project-pods-in-target-react).